# In Python 3, what is the most efficient way to change the values in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-efficient

I'm learning Python, and I was trying to change a list in different ways.  For instance, if I have list called names like this:

```
names = ["David", "Jake", "Alex"]
```

and I want to add the name "Carter" into the list, what is the most efficient way to accomplish this?  Here's some of the things I can do:

```
names.append("Carter")

names = names + ["Carter"]

names += ["Carter"]
```

Comment: I recommend using the `timeit` module to investigate this.

Comment: Premature optimization. Focus on idiom rather than efficiency at this point. Any work, `names.append("Carter")` is most idiomatic IMHO

Comment: @dawg, curious how you'd feel (in terms of idiomatic-ness) about `names = [*names, 'Carter']` in python 3.5

Comment: @PaulH: Ugly. Not obvious. Not idiomatic. Why do that?

Comment: the time difference would presumably be a matter of microseconds.  idiomatically,`names.append` is best because it's clear and obvious what you're doing to `names`.

Comment: generalized unpacking was a highly publicized enhancement of python 3.5. i'm just curious how the world is taking to it. (@dawg)

Comment: If bookended like this `[*list1, 'Carter', *list2, 'Bob']`  as opposed to `list1+['Carter']+list2+['Bob']` -- different story I suppose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

append is the fastest.
Here is how you build a small profile using the timeit module

```
import timeit
a = (timeit.timeit("l.append('Cheese')", setup="l=['Meat', 'Milk']"))
b = (timeit.timeit("l+=['Cheese']", setup="l=['Meat', 'Milk']"))
c = (timeit.timeit("append('Cheese')", setup="l=['Meat', 'Milk'];append = l.append"))
print ('a', a)
print ('b', b)
print ('c', c)
print ("==> " , (c < a < b))
```

As you can see, In python the access to the method append takes half of the time as the *l.append* itself...

> > > a 0.08502503100316972
> > >
> > > b 0.1582659209962003
> > >
> > > c 0.041991976962890476
> > >
> > > ==>  True

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timeit` package as shown in this [blog post](http://wordpress.allen-poole.com/wordpress/2011/11/benchmarx-continued-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-append-to-a-list-in-python/).

Here is a complete code running the tests 20000 times each test:

```
import timeit
t = 20000

print( "Addition (lst = lst + [4, 5, 6])" )
print( timeit.Timer("lst = lst + [4, 5, 6]", "lst = [1, 2, 3]").timeit(t) )
print( "Addition (lst += [4, 5, 6])" )
print( timeit.Timer("lst += [4, 5, 6]", "lst = [1, 2, 3]").timeit(t) )
print( "Extend (lst.extend([4, 5, 6]))" )
print( timeit.Timer("lst.extend([4, 5, 6])", "lst = [1, 2, 3]").timeit(t) )
print( "Append loop (lst.append([4, 5, 6]))" )
print( timeit.Timer("for i in [4,5,6]: lst.append(i)", "lst = [1,2,3]").timeit(t) )
print( "Append loop, no dot (a(i))" )
# a.b does a lookup, we don't want that, it is slower. Instead use b = a.b 
# then use b.
print( timeit.Timer("""a = lst.append
for i in [4,5,6]: a(i)""", "lst = [1,2,3]").timeit(t) )
```

And the results (Python 3.4.4) are:

```
Addition (lst = lst + [4, 5, 6])
1.947201736000352
Addition (lst += [4, 5, 6])
0.0015889199999037373
Extend (lst.extend([4, 5, 6]))
0.0020685689996753354
Append loop (lst.append([4, 5, 6]))
0.0047527769997941505
Append loop, no dot (a(i))
0.003853704999983165
```